# Have been getting no data from cordova-sqlite database with ionic. Console.Log() shows me insertId is undefined for every row in cordova-sqlite

Tags: android, cordova, ionic4, cordova-sqlite-storage

How to display data from cordova-sqlite database using ionic. I asked this question from the ionic framework forum. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/console-log-shows-me-insertid-is-undefined-for-every-row-in-cordova-sqlite/171787